# Using a User Inputted Value to Filter Values (Pandas, Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I would like to give the user of my program the ability to filter values in a column by a specific value of their choosing.  However, my code turns up the following error "Invalid Type Comparison".  Any ideas how to do this?

```
var2 = input("Enter Which Value you would like to filter by")
b = frame[(frame['Column1'] > var2)]
print(b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, easy solution.  Had to convert the value to a float

```
b= frame[(frame['Column1'] > float(var2))]
```